# Why do i getting such different scores in simple example?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch I have an index with 4 documents in it.
This is example of documents:

```
u'_source': {
 u'created': u'2016-04-02T15:32:45.395582+00:00',
 u'name': u'Jonny Preston',
 u'tags': [u'css', u'redis', u'php', u'memcache', u'html'],
 u'title': u'12',
...
},

u'_source': {
 u'created': u'2016-04-04T21:43:28.783034+00:00',
 u'name': u'test dt',
 u'tags': [u'redis', u'mysql', u'celery', u'postgressql'],
 u'title': u'title',
...
},
```

And when i'm trying to make query:

```
{'query': 
   {'bool': 
      {'should': [
         {'match': {'name': u'jonny'}},
         {'match': {'name': u'test'}}
      ]}
   }
}
```

I'm getting _score: 0.15891947 for the name 'jonny'
        and _score: 0.06155480 for the name 'test'

Why scores is so different in these simple examples?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html and, also, use `?explain` with your query to get a breakdown on how ES calculates the score.

Comment: This is strange as I have indexed the same documents you put in your example and got the same 0.028130025 score for both documents. I also recommend on using the `?explain` api: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I will use '?explain' api and will write an answer if it will be interesting)